# execute function after a dynamic div is loaded

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, bigcommerce

How do I make a JavaScript execute after a div section on the page is loaded? By using only standard JavaScript.

Here is the div section in question, extracted from (https://hera-warm-demo.mybigcommerce.com/checkout):

```
<div aria-busy="false" class="checkout-view-content checkout-view-content-enter-done">
  <div class="loading-skeleton">
    <div>
      <form class="checkout-form" data-test="payment-form" novalidate="">
        <fieldset class="form-fieldset">
          <div class="form-body">
            <ul class="form-checklist optimizedCheckout-form-checklist">
              <li class="form-checklist-item optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item form-checklist-item--selected optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item--selected">
                <div class="form-checklist-header form-checklist-header--selected">
                  <div class="form-field">
                    <label for="radio-bigpaypay" class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label">
                      <div class="paymentProviderHeader-container">
                        <div class="paymentProviderHeader-nameContainer" data-test="payment-method-bigpaypay">
                          <div aria-level="6" class="paymentProviderHeader-name" data-test="payment-method-name" role="heading">Test Payment Provider</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="paymentProviderHeader-cc">
                          <ul class="creditCardTypes-list"></ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This section is the last section on the page, and it only loads when the customer clicks "Continue" button from the previous section.

Here is the code I tried which didn't work.. I was expecting the JavaScript to execute after "checkout-view-content" div is loaded.

Note that I cannot include the script in the dynamically loaded HTML markup, I can only inject a JavaScript code.

```
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("checkout-view-content").addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
document.querySelector('label[for="radio-bigpaypay"] .paymentProviderHeader-cc').style.visibility = "hidden";
});
</script>
```

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` is an event on `document`, not some arbitrary element you choose - see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure CSS answer that shows you can change the visibility without needing javascript. My answer does include javascript just to show that the CSS still will apply to dynamic elements.

```
label[for="radio-bigpaypay"] .paymentProviderHeader-cc{visibility:hidden}
```

**UPDATE:**

Due to platform limitations, I have updated my answer. Now I'm creating a style element, adding the CSS to it then attaching it to the head.

Its not a perfect solution, but should still do the trick. You can always use visibility:hidden !important if you need ti.

```js
var sheet = document.createElement('style')
sheet.innerHTML = 'label[for="radio-bigpaypay"] .paymentProviderHeader-cc{visibility:hidden}';
document.head.appendChild(sheet);

const results = document.querySelector("#results");

results.innerHTML = `<div aria-busy="false" class="checkout-view-content checkout-view-content-enter-done">
  <div class="loading-skeleton">
    <div>
      <form class="checkout-form" data-test="payment-form" novalidate="">
        <fieldset class="form-fieldset">
          <div class="form-body">
            <ul class="form-checklist optimizedCheckout-form-checklist">
              <li class="form-checklist-item optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item form-checklist-item--selected optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item--selected">
                <div class="form-checklist-header form-checklist-header--selected">
                  <div class="form-field">
                    <label for="radio-bigpaypay" class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label">
                      <div class="paymentProviderHeader-container">
                        <div class="paymentProviderHeader-nameContainer" data-test="payment-method-bigpaypay">
                          <div aria-level="6" class="paymentProviderHeader-name" data-test="payment-method-name" role="heading">Test Payment Provider</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="paymentProviderHeader-cc">
                        HIDE ME
                          <ul class="creditCardTypes-list"></ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`;
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: BigCommerce requires me to make a copy of the theme to be able to edit the theme files, unfortunately I can't do that, that's why I am trying to hide that element using only JavaScript (they provide a way to inject JS codes without copying the theme).